# With the new Minecraft launcher, is there a way to change the .minecraft folder without manually specifying the Java path for every profile?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I am aware of the **--workDir** command line option, and I am using it to change the location of the .minecraft folder.  However, any profile I try to launch does not find the javaw.exe file (which is found in the workDir folder, as it should be in runtime\jre-x64\bin\javaw.exe).  It throws the following error:

```
Unable to locate the Java runtime.
Error details: The operation completed successfully.

Filename on disk: 
Path: .
Exists: Directory
```

If I manually specify the javaw.exe location, then it works.  My question is, why should I have to specify the javaw.exe file if it's in the default location already in the current **workDir**?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also, is the path to whatever Java version you want to use specified in the corresponding environment variable (how you do that depends on the operating system and if you need to do that or not depends on your setup)?

Comment: @FabianRöling I'm using Windows 10.  I shouldn't need an environment variable set because Minecraft includes a JRE with the installation.

Comment: But apparently it points to the JRE in the default location. So maybe adding it to the environment variable works anyway.